# Changing some column name in R

Tags: r

I would like to change the column names of my 4th and 5th column with this code, but it is not working.

```
colnames(df[,4:5]) <- paste(colnames(df[,4:5]), "13", sep= "_")
```

It works if I remove [,4:5] and change the column names for the whole data frame.

```
colnames(df) <- paste(colnames(df), "13", sep= "_")
```

but my desired output is just to change the 4th and 5th column. Thanks.

Comment: try ```colnames(df)[4:5] = paste(colnames(df)[4:5], "13", sep="_")```.

Comment: @user438383 has it. You want to assign values to the `colnames` vector, not the data frame row.

Answer (score 3):

It is much easier to do with `dplyr::rename()`.

Simply use `df %>% rename(new_name = old_name)`, and you're done!

Here is an example

```
library(dplyr)
head(mtcars, n = 2)
              mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4      21   6  160 110  3.9 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4

mtcars_new = mtcars %>% rename(new_mpg = mpg)

head(mtcars_new, n = 2)
              new_mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4          21   6  160 110  3.9 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag      21   6  160 110  3.9 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `replace` like below

```
setNames(df, replace(names(df), 4:5, paste(names(df)[4:5], "13", sep = "_")))
```